# regex for nested parentheses

Tags: c#, regex

### Brief

I have the following text:

> [atdSd[asdasd<4REGEH22>asdosy]   ***oopprefs[ew<16REGEH30>rdtr]pppp555b

My matches should be as follows:

1. `[asdasd<4REGEH22>asdosy]`
2. `[ew<16REGEH30>rdtr]`

### My attempts

I have tried to make it on my own but the result was:

1. `[atdSd[asdasd<4REGEH22>asdosy]`
2. `[ew<16REGEH30>rdtr]`

I am using the following expression:

```
\[\S+<(\d+)REGEH(\d+)>\S+\]
```

### Specifics

The conditions are:

- You must have no whitespaces inside the match.
- Inside the match you must have [(ASCII Symbols)<(Some digits)REGEH(Some digits)>(ASCII Symbols)]
- If you have nested brackets you need to match the inner most.
  `[asdSd[asdasd<4REGEH23>asdUsd]` should match `[asdasd<4REGEH23>asdUsd]`

An example that should yield no matches

> [atdSd[<4REGEH22>asdosy]   ***oopprefs[ew<16REGEH>rdtr]pppp555b

### Question

How can I match the inner parentheses?

Answer (score 1):

```
  var st = "[atdSd[asdasd<4REGEH22>asdosy] ***oopprefs[ew<16REGEH30>rdtr]pppp555b";

        List<string> result = new List<string>
                            (Regex.Matches(st, @"\[[^[]+REGEH.*?\]")
                            .Cast<Match>()
                            .Select(x => x.Value)
                            .ToList());

        // [asdasd<4REGEH22>asdosy] [ew<16REGEH30>rdtr]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

`\[[^\s\[]+<(\d+)REGEH(\d+)>[[^\s\[]+\]`

Basically replaced the `\S` with `[^\s\[]`, ie a negated char class matching for not whitepsace chars and, crucially - for not `[`.

http://regexr.com/3glld

Comment: Thank you very much mate

Comment: No problem -  if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.